# Minecraft 1.12.2 How to /clear item that have a specific enchant and name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen examples of how to clear items with specific name or enchants but not both.

This is what I have so far:

```
/clear @p minecraft:paper 0 1 {tag:{ench:[{id:16s,lvl:1s}]}},{display:{name:"custom name"}}
```

output: data tag parsing failed: trailing data found at: {tag:{ench:[{id:16s,lvl:1s}]}},<--[here]

Comment: You're missing some braces, you've got unbalanced brackets, and there might some other errors in your command.  It would also help if you included the error message that you get when you run this command.

Answer (score 0):

I’m expanding your command and pointing out all the errors in it:

```
/clear @p minecraft:paper 0 1
{ 
    tag:{  # “tag” should not be used in /clear command
        ench:[
            {
                id:16s,
                lvl:1s
            }
        ]
    }
}, # this extra “}” closes the final tag before you get to the display section.
{
    display:{
        name:"custom name" # “Name” misspelled as “name”
    }
}
```

So in summary:

- Don’t use `tag` in the `/clear` command.
- Make sure you are balancing your brackets. You used one too many `}`s.
- The `name` tag is misspelled. Correct tag is `Name`.

Fixed command:

```
/clear @p minecraft:paper 0 1
{
    ench:[
        {
            id:16s,
            lvl:1s
        }
    ],
    display:{
        Name:"custom name"
    }
}
```